# Can l2tp carry IGMP packet?

Tags: l2tp, igmp

If a client connects to one vpn server, can it join a video meeting which is based on IGMP?

Answer (score 1):

[RFC4045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4045) describes extensions to support multicast over L2TP protocol. So, it seems possible, but it depends on the implementation you use.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Khaled had written, there are other encapsulation protocols which would support Multicast encapsulation - [GRE for example](http://www.cisco.com/application/pdf/en/us/guest/netsol/ns171/c649/ccmigration_09186a008074f26a.pdf). Most "multicast tunneling" techniques allow multicast transmissions to cross unicast-only networks using GRE. The more advanced and flexible version of tunneling is [AMT](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-mboned-auto-multicast-11.txt) which is in the standardization process for about a decade now, but [has working implementations](http://sites.google.com/site/amtproxy/) and [sees some use](http://tech.ebu.ch/docs/techreview/trev_2010-Q4_AMT_Kernen_Simlo.pdf).